# Mockito: Mocking method that is not yet defined but know the return type

Tags: java, scala, mockito

I have a method yet to be defined, but the return type is known. Is there a way I can still mock this method and test the return to match with the return type?

```
def getX(a: String): Future[returnType]
```

```
when(someService.getX(a)).thenReturn(Future.successful(returnType))
```

Comment: But even if it would be possible, what code is tested then? If you mock a method and then you verify its (mocked method's) return type?

Comment: In my current situation, it would not be testing the method itself, but rather by passing this method so the unit test for the service as a whole can pass.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for [???](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/what-does-three-question-marks-in-scala-mean).

You can define your method like:

```
def getX(a: String): Future[returnType] = ???
```

Then you could reference it in your tests or other code and everything would compile, but calling it will fail at runtime with `NotImplementedError` thrown. It will also fail in tests unless you override it in mock.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. I am actually trying to pass the test while mocking the method but by passing the ```NotImplementedError``` What is the best way to override it in mock? Thanks!

Comment: If you could share more details how do you want to use that method in your testcase I could give you more details.